# Default for fastest-code or restricted-time challenge

Tags: discussion, policy

Because it would be hard for newcomers to find and read all of the meta questions about this topic, I suggest having a common post for all of them. It would be easier for moderators to point newcomers at a single post instead of multiple meta posts.

Related questions:

[What is the best way to actually time an answer for fastest-code challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/what-is-the-best-way-to-actually-time-an-answer-for-fastest-code-challenges)

[comparing fastest code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/comparing-fastest-code?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[Would language restrictions for fastest-code problems be ok?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/would-language-restrictions-for-fastest-code-problems-be-ok?rq=1)

[Is TIO acceptable for fastest-code questions?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/is-tio-acceptable-for-fastest-code-questions)

[Winning Criteria vs Valid Criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/winning-criteria-vs-valid-criteria)

---

What are the requirements for writing a [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge?